# Why can't i access the facts_text_view id in the activity?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a fun facts activity that takes a random fact from an activity and displays it on the layout. But I cannot access the *fact_text_view* in the activity even though it's defined in the layout. How can I improve this?

**ACTIVITY CODE**

```
public class FunFactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random r =new Random();
    List list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        //adds facts to the list.
        for (int i = 0; i < new Database().answers.length; i++) {
            list.add(new Database().facts[i]);

        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        String fact = String.valueOf(r.nextInt(list.size()));
        TextView factTextView = findViewById(facts_text_view);
        factTextView.setText(fact);

    }
}
```

**LAYOUT CODE**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/facts_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to access it this way :

```
TextView factTextView = findViewById(R.id.facts_text_view);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this problem because you are not accessing textview I'd properly

Change your textview like below

```
TextView factTextView = findViewById(R.id.facts_text_view);
```